# Getting JSON values from string in SQL

Tags: sql, json

I am trying to get the 'serial_numbers' from each of the different 'item-id' in this this:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json=N'[{
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "order_id": 79727,
      "original_transaction_date": "2020-04-04T21:31:13.270741+08:00",
      "order_lines": [
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 320,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 1,
          "item_id": 9982,
          "item_sku": "SP7",
          "product_id": 978,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Portable Microcurrent & Electrolysis Generator",
          "local_customs_description": "便携式微电流和电解发生器",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 15,
          "description": "Silver Pulser 7",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "SP000000001"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 0.793,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "ship_ready",
          "harmonized_code": "8543.70.00.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/e8ea41b3cf424dca9cbbbffd5613dd19.jpg",
          "gross_length": 20,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "SP7",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 8,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        },
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 225,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 2,
          "item_id": 9970,
          "item_sku": "LWP1",
          "product_id": 968,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Flexible LED Light Pad",
          "local_customs_description": "",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 18,
          "description": "Lightworks Pad 1",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "LP000000001",
            "LP000000002"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 2.2,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "xxxx",
          "harmonized_code": "8541.40.20.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/554f8f49363e437c80746618b21d909d.jpg",
          "gross_length": 8,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "LWP1",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 33,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        },
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 395,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 3,
          "item_id": 9980,
          "item_sku": "MP6",
          "product_id": 977,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Portable Magnetic Field Generator",
          "local_customs_description": "便携式磁场发生器",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 22,
          "description": "Magnetic Pulser 6",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "MP000000001",
            "MP000000002",
            "MP000000003"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 2.2,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "xxxxx",
          "harmonized_code": "8543.70.00.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/c03243581aa847adb172d4d90fcf71d2.jpg",
          "gross_length": 35,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "MP6",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 9,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        }
      ],
      "shipping_address": {
        "country": "CA",
        "addressee": "Roger Rabbit",
        "address_1": "123 Bunny Hole Lane",
        "address_2": "",
        "address_3": "",
        "city": "Peter Cottontail Town",
        "state": "BC",
        "postal_code": "V0H1K0",
        "company": "",
        "phone": "2505551212",
        "email": "jd@sota.com",
        "tax_id": ""
      },
      "is_editable": false,
      "status": "fulfilled",
      "exception_code": "does_not_meet_courier_requirements___restrictions",
      "tax_paid_by": "dap",
      "insurance_value": {
        "amount": 50,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "shipping_cost_value": null,
      "shipping_cost_value_tax": null,
      "source": "Fulfillment Portal",
      "customer_reference": "12345678",
      "reference": "FS0079727",
      "create_date": "2020-04-04T21:31:13.289517+08:00",
      "update_date": "2020-04-04T23:16:48.407941+08:00",
      "shipment_date": "2020-04-04T21:31:13.275002+08:00",
      "courier_id": 20,
      "courier": {
        "courier_id": 20,
        "name": "Hong Kong Post Air Parcel",
        "aftership_slug": null
      },
      "tracking_number": "KK9813xxxx97006HK",
      "tracking_url": "https://track.aftership.com/xxxx",
      "tracking_status": null,
      "customer_shipping_option": "",
      "order_type": "stock",
      "cancellation_fee": "3.00",
      "fulfilment_date": "2020-04-04T23:15:31.982284+08:00",
      "warehouse": {
        "name": "Warehouse #1",
        "id": 11,
        "local_address": "仓库本地地址18",
        "default_address": "55 xxxxxxSt, Suite 512, Tsing Yi,  HK, HK, 852 3706 8391"
      },
      "tags": [],
      "reason_of_export": "purchase",
      "remarks": "",
      "commercial_invoice": "https://xxxxx-shipping.s3.amazonaws.com/commercial_invoice/a8dd5bb8f72f44a8a2537b7a29bac347.pdf",
      "shipping_label": null,
      "attachment_file": null
    }
  ]
}]' 
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
      OrderID   VARCHAR(200)  '$.results[0].order_id' ,
      SNs   VARCHAR(200)  '$.serial_numbers' 
)
```

I am trying to use the With clause but am very new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you edit your post and explain how it’s not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[{
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "order_id": 79727,
      "original_transaction_date": "2020-04-04T21:31:13.270741+08:00",
      "order_lines": [
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 320,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 1,
          "item_id": 9982,
          "item_sku": "SP7",
          "product_id": 978,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Portable Microcurrent & Electrolysis Generator",
          "local_customs_description": "便携式微电流和电解发生器",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 15,
          "description": "Silver Pulser 7",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "SP000000001"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 0.793,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "ship_ready",
          "harmonized_code": "8543.70.00.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/e8ea41b3cf424dca9cbbbffd5613dd19.jpg",
          "gross_length": 20,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "SP7",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 8,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        },
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 225,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 2,
          "item_id": 9970,
          "item_sku": "LWP1",
          "product_id": 968,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Flexible LED Light Pad",
          "local_customs_description": "",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 18,
          "description": "Lightworks Pad 1",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "LP000000001",
            "LP000000002"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 2.2,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "xxxx",
          "harmonized_code": "8541.40.20.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/554f8f49363e437c80746618b21d909d.jpg",
          "gross_length": 8,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "LWP1",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 33,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        },
        {
          "customs_value": {
            "amount": 395,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "quantity": 3,
          "item_id": 9980,
          "item_sku": "MP6",
          "product_id": 977,
          "has_batteries": false,
          "customs_description": "Portable Magnetic Field Generator",
          "local_customs_description": "便携式磁场发生器",
          "has_expiration": false,
          "gross_width": 22,
          "description": "Magnetic Pulser 6",
          "serial_numbers": [
            "MP000000001",
            "MP000000002",
            "MP000000003"
          ],
          "gross_weight": 2.2,
          "product_quantity": 1,
          "packaging_type": "xxxxx",
          "harmonized_code": "8543.70.00.00",
          "item_type": "base_item",
          "upc": null,
          "nmfc": null,
          "image_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxx-client-uploads/items/images/photo/c03243581aa847adb172d4d90fcf71d2.jpg",
          "gross_length": 35,
          "has_liquids": false,
          "customs_category": "",
          "country_of_manufacture": "CN",
          "sku": "MP6",
          "carton_sku": null,
          "gross_height": 9,
          "tax": null,
          "duty": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]' 

SELECT item.item_id, sn.value AS serial_number FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].results') AS res 
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(res.value, '$.order_lines') 
  WITH ( item_id INT '$.item_id', serial_numbers NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.serial_numbers' AS JSON ) AS item 
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(item.serial_numbers) AS sn;
```

| item_id | serial_number |
| --- | --- |
| 9982 | SP000000001 |
| 9970 | LP000000001 |
| 9970 | LP000000002 |
| 9980 | MP000000001 |
| 9980 | MP000000002 |
| 9980 | MP000000003 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wl51Ofle)